# Why App is Crashing while calling GPS?

Tags: android, android-studio, locationlistener, crash

```
package com.example.simranjeet.myapplication43;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class GpsLocation extends AppCompatActivity {
    Context context;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private LocationListener listener;


    void findloc(){
        locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        listener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

                Intent i = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        };

        configure_button();
    }
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode){
            case 10:
                configure_button();
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    void configure_button(){
        // first check for permissions
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,Manifest.permission.INTERNET}
                        ,10);
            }
            return;
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates("gps", 500, 0, listener);
        // locationManager.requestSingleUpdate(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,listener,null);
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
       Toast.makeText(context,"location finded",Toast.LENGTH_LONG ).show();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(listener);
        // Location lastKnownLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }
}
```

I'm calling `findloc` method from `onCreate` method as

```
s = new GpsLocation();
s.findloc();
```

every time i call this function it crashed but it is working well when it 
is not placed in seprate class. i have added every permission and it is 
working pretty good when it is under onCreate method can anybody tell me why it is abruptly crashing.

CRASH LOG//i am using emulator

> Process: com.example.simranjeet.myapplication43, PID: 12956
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.simranjeet.myapplication43/com.example.simranjeet.myapplication43.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to
>   Activities before onCreate()
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>            Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>               at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5253)
>               at com.example.simranjeet.myapplication43.GpsLocation.findloc(GpsLocation.java:25)
>               at com.example.simranjeet.myapplication43.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
>       07-20 13:01:03.413 3353-12581/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler: Unrecognised action provided:
>   android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED

Comment: Can you share crash log?

Comment: You are not supposed to create an instance of Activity in Android explicitly. If your GpsLocation class is intended to be some sort of helper class then don't extend `AppCompatActivity`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

instead

```
 locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: same error again ,i also tried to pass context but it is also not working

Comment: not working i have also tried this one too by removing extend appcompactactivity locationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Comment: @Simranjeet must be another error if you use appContext. Can you share it?